# Can you label views in AutoLayout console output without using Storyboards?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout

I'm watching through the WWDC talks on AutoLayout, and I've learned that having StoryboardID set on your views makes the console output for constraint conflicts much easier to read (i.e. you get a name instead of just an address). They show you where to set the StoryboardID (formerly just "Identifier") in Interface Builder, but is there a way to do it in code? I'm trying to debug a large and complicated set of views that I didn't write myself, in an app that's 100% programmatic, that has many unsatisfiable constraints, and that was (somehow) working in iOS 7 but started breaking in iOS 8. I would love to get a clear picture of which `<UIView:0x8675309>` is actually causing the problem.

I looked over the UIView class reference, no "Identifier" or "StoryboardID" to be found.

Wouldn't be too surprised if the answer is "nope". After all it's called a Storyboard ID for a reason. But I would appreciate a confirmation, and a workaround to make the AutoLayout console dump more readable if possible.

Comment: Obviously there is no storyboard in this story so there is no storyboard id. What is it that you _really_ want to know? I mean, it seems this has something to do with identifying views in the console, is that right? So why not ask about _that_? Explain what the problem _really_ is. What are you trying to do, and why can't you do it?

Comment: Because the WWDC talk says that the way to do it is to set the Identifier in IB. I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: IMO, there's nothing wrong with the app being 100% programmatic. I've done both & I prefer it being programmatic if you're going to be maintaining the product for awhile.

Comment: @matt - I think you are being unduly harsh, I read the headline and understand _exactly_ what the question was and why a solution would be useful // _correction_ ... this  comment was posted _after_ Garret edited the question!

Comment: @matt thanks for helping me focus my question!

Comment: @foundry I don't agree - the way the question was originally posed, it was way too narrow and unanswerable: the only possible answer was just No (i.e. there is no storyboard ID if you aren't using a storyboard). It wasn't really a question, even. Now, however, the OP has rewritten the question to ask about an actual task he's trying to perform - and I've got a suggestion about how he can do it! That is exactly what my comment was trying to get him to do - and exactly what comments are for.

Comment: From what I understand, those identifiers only work for OS X autolayout tracing, not for iOS, assuming we're talking about the "identifier" in the Identity inspector, not actually a Storyboard ID...

Comment: @matt - my comment was based on reading the _revised_ question - that's why I didn't understand your objections: Garrett had already responded to them. Apologies for the misunderstanding. Anyway I have posted an answer which extends yours a little in ways Garret may find useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would love to get a clear picture of which  is actually causing the problem.

I have two suggestions.

1. In Xcode, during the same run of the app (preferably right after you get are given some sort of console dump about the constraints), choose Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy.

   The app pauses and you are shown your view hierarchy. Select a view and you are shown its memory address in the Object Inspector. When you find the one whose address is `0x8675309`, that's the one. Plus you can see the constraints that position this view in the Size Inspector.
2. Implement the constraint logger utilities that I provide in my book. The second one reports the view hierarchy along with the identifiers and the constraints.

Here are the utilities; between them, I've saved hours of puzzlement:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    class func reportAmbiguity (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as [UIView] {
            println("\(vv) \(vv.hasAmbiguousLayout())")
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.reportAmbiguity(vv)
            }
        }
    }
    class func listConstraints (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as [UIView] {
            let arr1 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Horizontal)
            let arr2 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical)
            NSLog("\n\n%@\nH: %@\nV:%@", vv, arr1, arr2);
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.listConstraints(vv)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The concept of mapping views to addresses using the Capture View Heirarchy feature is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I'm a little late to the party, but I hope this helps. There is indeed an extremely simple attribute on UIView, through it's conformance to [UIAccessibilityIdentification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiaccessibilityidentification):

```
centerView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Center Foobar View"
containerView.accessibilityIdentifier = "Container BingBat View"
```

This yields debugger output like you'd expect:

> `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe3fa3ade50 Center Foobar View.centerX == Container BingBat View.centerX   (Names: Center Foobar View:0x7fe3fa3a1700, Container BingBat View:0x7fe3fa3856c0 )>"`,

Comment: Heh, I don't do objective-C anymore, but this does look like exactly what I was looking for at the time. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! I know it helped me :-) I was actually looking for what to use to get them labeled in the View Hierarchy list when you pause the debugger - turns out that's different - the Accessibility Label.

Answer (score 1):

[Erica Sadun](http://ericasadun.com) has a fairly cool suggestion in her book on NSLayout (*iOS Auto Layout Demystified*). UIView has a 'tag' property that can only accept an NSInteger. With an appropriately crafted category on UIView (or indeed on NSObject) we can add a "viewName" property - which accepts a string - using associated objects:

```
//UIView+viewName.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIView (NameTagO)

- (NSString*)viewName;
- (void)setViewName:(NSString*)viewName;

@end

//UIView+viewName.m
#import "UIView+viewName.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@implementation UIView (viewName)

- (NSString*)viewName {
    return (NSString*)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(viewName));

}
- (void)setViewName:(NSString*)name {
    NSParameterAssert([viewName isKindOfClass:NSString.class]);
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self
                             , @selector(viewName)
                             , name
                             , OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Then you can add a string tag to a view:

```
   UIView* view = [UIView alloc] init..];
   view.viewName = @"name";
```

logging:

```
   NSLog(%@"view: %@",view.viewName)
```

There is a really good concise [explanation of associated objects on the NSHipster blog](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) which has just been [revisited for Swift](http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/)

Here is a swift-ified version of the `viewName` category:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var viewName = "foundry_viewName"
    }

    var viewName: String? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.viewName) as? String
        }
        set {
            if let newValue = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(
                    self,
                    &AssociatedKeys.viewName,
                    newValue as NSString?,
                    UInt(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
                )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It could just as well be a category on NSObject, although in this context it is it's use on UIView that we are interested in. With this category you can give your views meaningful labels for logging and extraction purposes. For example, you could use this approach in conjunction with the logger Matt describes in his answer (which comes from his [really comprehensive book on iOS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034261.do)) to log views using meaningful names.

When creating a view, you would set its viewName:

```
let view: UIView = UIView.init()
view.viewName = "test"
```

Then Matt's `reportAmbiguity` function could be extended a little:

```
class func reportAmbiguity (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as [UIView] {
            let viewName = vv.viewName?
            if (viewName != nil) {
                println("\view \(vv.viewName) \(vv.hasAmbiguousLayout())")
            } else {
                println("\(vv) \(vv.hasAmbiguousLayout())")
            }
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                //self.reportAmbiguity(vv)
            }
        }
    }
```

The only annoyance is having to unpack the `viewName` optional. You don't *have* to do this, but if you don't the string interpolation will report 'Optional("test")' which is a little cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks for the logging ideas, I'll give them a shot.