# How to see objects that set UIAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints?

Tags: ios, constraints

> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
>
> Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17ece100 H:[UIView:0x17eaa690(86.6667)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17eb5200 UIButton:0x17d82f60.leading == UIView:0x17eaa690.leading + 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17ecf820 UIButton:0x17d82f60.trailing == UIView:0x17eaa690.trailing - 5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17ed0020 H:[UIButton:0x17d82f60(73.3333)]>"
)
```

I tried setting symbolic breakepoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints but app just stops, here i saw this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389273/how-to-trap-on-uiviewalertforunsatisfiableconstraints)

All i want to see, which button or view is there?

> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x191f0920 H:[MPKnockoutButton:0x17a876b0]-(34)-[MPDetailSlider:0x17a8bc50](LTR)>
```

Comment: It's perfectly obvious what's wrong with the constraints. Is that what you want to know? I can't even figure out what your question is.

Comment: i know what is wrong with the constraints, but i dont know which constraints are the problem, in my warning it says UIButton:0x1239123, in his its the name of the button? or i am wrong

Comment: Well, I still don't quite understand what the question is, so I've given an answer, and if it doesn't help you, make a comment and I can expand the answer.

Comment: ok, since i dont know better, ill try this way, i have a UIButton xButton, and a UIView xView, is there a way to see variable names instead of just classes

Comment: No, there isn't, because at the time the code runs, there are no variable names. Source code is not object code. The runtime is telling you the object's memory address at that moment - that is the only unique identifier there is.

Comment: that is what i wanted to know, last question, can i get what i want by setting symbolic breakpoint?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28204193/341994 Your question is basically a duplicate of that one.